# Best similaity (dissimilarity) measure among multidimensions categorical vectors

Tags: uitableview, cluster-analysis, data-mining, data-analysis

I would like to find similarity ( dissimilarity ) among the following data points :

my categorical data set as follow:  { Art , Science , Math.s , medical , physics , chemistry , engineering ..etc } for example 15 or 20 category .

so I would like to find Sim(Dis) among these libraries which each library row ( data points ) represent the rows vectors ,

```
                                         Books attributes 
libraries  total-books    Art       science    Math.         chemistry  
 lib1          1000        50         200      0              3
 lib2          500         12         0        0              44
 lib3   etc..
```

table here represent the number of books found in each library , when we found its frequency percentage to total books found then re-arrangement the representation of categories for each library based on frequency percentage for example 
I'm not consider the zero category in the following vectors ,

library 1 = { science ,Art , chemistry , ... }
library 2 = { Chemistry , Art , ....  }
etc...

How to find similarity / dissimilarity between lib1 and lib2 and etc...

any suggestion please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you normalize by the total number of books. you can treat the remaining columns as a *histogram*.

Then you could try any of the distribution-based distances:

- histogram intersection distance
- kullback-leibler-divergence
- $\chi^2$ distance
- Jensen-Shannon divergence

Comment: thanks Anony-Mousse  , I found only the frequency of each category in each row for example Art book in lib1 is 50 and total books in lib1 is 1000 then [ 30/1000] * 100% will give me value , I repeat all process for remaining categories and also same above process for all libraries , then I arrangement the order of each category in each library , so each libi ,I=1..n will give vectors of non-zero category , is my process consider normalization , and please do you have explanation for your great note , you will help me more in that , thanks again

Comment: i request that because your specialist in data mining , cluster analysis , that's i need some notes from you , thanks again

Comment: Why do you think reordering makes things easier to process for a computer? Try to keep the order fixed, and **look at the methods I suggested**. They work well on some data sets, whereas I have doubts your approach will be useful.

Comment: sir , I just give my though , I need an assistant to analysis my problem , so do you mean each libi(I=1..n ) give different histogram then find according to your methods the different among these rows (lib(I)) , finally is there any example about this , what I have to do , presently I'm studing notes about your methods , thanks very great work sir

Comment: my specialist in different area from data mining , so how to find similar libraries as possible , please suggest me solution for cluster analysis